# sql oracle compare string that contains substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using sql Oracle and I have in my DB  a table with some values for action . For example:

```
id  action
1   REH001
2   REH002
3   REH003
4   LOA001
5   LOA002
6   RFL
```

I want to get the id if the action matches a substring of multiple values (with delimiter ;)

for example I want to compare it to the string `LOA;RFL`
So I want to get the id if the 3 first chars are equal to LOA or RFL. 
For this example it has to returns the ids 4,5 and 6

But it is not always the 3 first chars. For example I want to get the ids for the match with the substring `REH003;TRE`
For my example this will return me the id 3

I tried to simplify my question, because it is very difficult to explain, but I think you will understand with my examples.

Comment: where is the string coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the input string to a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(action, '^(' || replace(:compare_string, ';', '|') || ')')
```

Comment: OP said search strings are not always 3 characters

Answer (score 1):

check this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc1e8f/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("id" int, action varchar2(6))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (1, 'REH001')
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (2, 'REH002')
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (3, 'REH003')
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (4, 'LOA001')
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (5, 'LOA002')
    INTO t ("id", action)
         VALUES (6, 'RFL')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte0 as 
(
   select trim(regexp_substr(c, '[^;]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as r from 
  (
     select 'LOA001;RFL' c FROM DUAL
  ) ti,
    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
        connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(c, '[^;]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
)
select * from cte0
inner join t on substr(action, 1,length(r)) = r
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc1e8f/11/0)**:

```
|      R | id | ACTION |
|--------|----|--------|
| LOA001 |  4 | LOA001 |
|    RFL |  6 |    RFL |
```